# Does updating a column with foregin key contraint can lock the referenced table?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, database-locking, postgres-10

I have one table, which is heavily updated in my system by process A. This is the simplified table:

```
db=# \d employee;
                                       Table "public.employee"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('employee_id_seq'::regclass)
 name            | character varying           |           |          |

Indexes:
"employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

And I have a table which is referencing that table:

```
db=# \d employee_property;
                                       Table "public.employee_property"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('employee_property_id_seq'::regclass)
 type            | character varying           |           |          |
 value           | character varying           |           |          |
 employee_id     | integer                     |           | not null |

Indexes:
    "employee_property_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "employee_property_employee_id_type_value_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (employee_id, type, value)
    "ix_employee_property_employee_id" btree (employee_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
   "employee_property_employee_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(employee_id) ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE
```

I am trying to understand if I am updating the `employee_property` table heavily by process B in the system, might it cause some locks or any other side effects which might affect the process A which updates the employee table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert a row in `employee_property` or update the `employee_id` column of an existing row, a `FOR KEY SHARE` lock is placed on the row the new `employee_id` refers to.

This lock will block any concurrent attempt to delete the referenced `employee` row or update any `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` columns. Updates to the locked `employee` row that do not modify a key column will work, because they only require a `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` lock on the row, which is compatible with `FOR KEY SHARE`.

The reason for this is that PostgreSQL must ensure that the referenced row cannot vanish while the transaction that modifies `employee_property` is still in progress. Simply checking for referencing rows in `employee` won't be enough, because the effects of a transaction that is still in progress are not visible outside the transaction itself.